# Are the ROS Answers questions marked as migrated in the API?

Tags: bug, ros-migration, migration

If you look at [this question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/29438/which-data-types-does-tf-use) it is clearly marked as coming from ROS Answers.

However, if you look at it from [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/29438?order=desc&sort=activity&site=robotics), the question does not contain the [migrated_from](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) field.

Is this because it was migrated from a non-stack-exchange platform?

Is there another way to tell that it was migrated other than fetching the body and parsing for the link back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `migrated_from` field is I think is a metadata flag for questions that are moved by the mods between Stack Exchange sites.

The migration in from ROS Answers was a custom import and as far as I know the migration metadata was only captured in the body of the content. As the one time content doesn't justify customized metadata for all of stack exchange.